# Failed to resolve: firebase-crash-15.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I'm trying to connect firebase to my application. I successfully added **firebase-core** to my build.gradle file and project synced correctly, but when I want to add  *firebase-crash* for crash reporting I got this error:
"Failed to resolve: firebase-crash-15.0.0"

my build.gradle (Module) file:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.1:15.0.0'
...
}
```

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

I also added **classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'** to my build.gradle (Project) too and it synced successfully.

any idea? :|

Comment: Firebase Crash Reporting is discontinued.  Use Crashlytics instead.

Comment: You have to integrate crashlytics instead of firebase-crash, check out their Get Started guide:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started#android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:** This line make your gradle sync failed.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.1:15.0.0'
```

Because there is no version `16.0.1:15.0.0`

**Solution:** If you want to use version `15.0.0`

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:15.0.0'
```

Or using the latest version `16.2.1`

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
```

You can pick your expectation version [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-crash).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.1:15.0.0'
add   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.1'